# Can you add a href link around an image file in Editor.js?

Tags: javascript, editorjs

I am wondering if EditorJs has the functionality to add a href link around an image file in Editor.js? I am able to select an image but I like to be able to add an external link to that image file so it renders in data blocks. I want to be able to save this as a JSON file.

Right now it only outputs the image file like below. I want add a link to this output.
It doesn't seem to have a place to add a link to an image

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@editorjs/image@latest

Basically I like to prompt an alert box with an input field to enter the external url and attach it to that image after the image file is selected. This should be inserted into the JSON output as well.

```
{
        "id" : "nyCVy7Sf9U",
        "type" : "image",
        "data" : {
            "file" : {
                "url" : "example.jpg"
            },
            "caption" : "",
            "withBorder" : false,
            "stretched" : false,
            "withBackground" : false
        }
    },
```